# JButton listener not firing

Tags: java, swing, button, actionlistener

I seperated my codes into MVC model and now my confirm button action listener is not printing the username and password even though I added a Actionlistener for it. please help thanks.

Codes

LoginDialog.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginDialog extends JDialog {

    private JLabel nameLabel;
    private JLabel passwordLabel;
    private JTextField usernameTF;
    private JPasswordField passwordTF;
    private JButton confirmBtn;
    private JButton cancelBtn;
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc;

    public LoginDialog() {
        this.setTitle("Authentication");

        topPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        nameLabel = new JLabel("Name : ");
        passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password : ");
        usernameTF = new JTextField();
        passwordTF = new JPasswordField();
        confirmBtn = new JButton("Confirm");
        cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
        buttonPanel.add(confirmBtn);
        buttonPanel.add(cancelBtn);
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        topPanel.add(nameLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        topPanel.add(usernameTF, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        topPanel.add(passwordLabel, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        topPanel.add(passwordTF, gbc);

        this.add(topPanel);
        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void showLoginDialog() {
        LoginDialog ld = new LoginDialog();
        ld.setSize(400, 150);
        ld.setVisible(true);
        ld.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return usernameTF.getText();
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return new String(passwordTF.getPassword());
    }

    public void confirmBtnListner(ActionListener listener) {
        confirmBtn.addActionListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Controller {

    private LoginDialog loginDialog;

    public Controller(LoginDialog loginDialog) {
        this.loginDialog = loginDialog;
        loginDialog.showLoginDialog();
        loginDialog.confirmBtnListner(new BtnListener());
    }

    class BtnListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(loginDialog.getUsername());
            System.out.println(loginDialog.getPassword());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoginDialog loginDialog = new LoginDialog();
        new Controller(loginDialog);
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  In this case, it would need to be one source file with at most one **`public`** class (+ other classes that are more restricted access) and a `main(String[])` method.

Comment: I did have a main(String[] args) method and my post is already MCVE??

Comment: This is not a proper MVC

Comment: @samlee  I missed the `main` method.  Seems you missed my first point about 'one source file'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having two instances of `LoginDialog` class.

One you are creating in your controller and the other one is in your `LoginDialog#showLoginDialog()` method.

Let's list them:

```
1st instance - In the controller class named `loginDialog`
2nd instance - In the `LoginDialog` class named `ld`
```

Here `ld` is an object created within `loginDialog` object. But they are two different `JDialog` objects. When you call

```
loginDialog.showLoginDialog()
```

another object `ld` is created from within the method. The `JDialog` refered is set to visible by:

```
ld.setVisible(true)
```

So now,

```
Object `ld` is visible
And Object `loginDialog` is NOT yet visible as you havent done `loginDialog.setVisible(true)` yet.
```

Now are adding the `ActionListener` to the button within `loginDialog` object, which is not yet visible. While there is no `ActionListener` added to the Button within `ld` object.

## Final conclusion:

1. Object `ld` is visible, but button within it has **NO** `ActionListener`.
2. Object `loginDialog` is **NOT** yet visible. But the button within it has an `ActionListener`.
3. The button you are clicking is a part of `ld` object which has **NO** action listener associated to it.
4. The button which has an `ActionListener` associated to it is a part of `loginDialog` object which is **NOT** visible.

## Wanna check if I am right?

Just add these lines in your controller constructor:

```
loginDialog.setVisible(true);
loginDialog.setSize(400, 150);
loginDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

I won't give you the full solution as we don't spoonfeed here on stack overflow. So it's a challange for you to adjust your code accordingly. :)

Comment: you mentioned in the comment above that my codes is not a proper MVC. How then should I make it into a proper MVC?

Comment: GUI part goes in the View. Buissness logic goes in the Model. And controller, you know. Well this app is very small for an MVC pattern. You will over complicate things. It's better not to use MVC for small apps like this.

Answer (score 2):

The method `showLoginDialog()` creates a new instance of your dialog, which does not have the `actionlistener`.

fix: don't create a new instance - use the one you have.

```
    public void showLoginDialog() {
        setSize(400, 150);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
```